# CHM pitfree error : "Not a matrix"

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

I use the pitfree algorithm to create the CHM of 89 .LAS files.

```
chm = grid_canopy(lasnorm, 0.5, pitfree(thresholds = c(0,2,5,10,15,20), subcircle = 0.2))
```

In the entire code, I go trough each files to produce a segmentation raster with some metrics. Depending on the settings I use for the pitfree algorithm, I will get an error on different LAS files.

I tried to change the parameters (resolution, subcircle, thresholds), but each time I would end out having that same error ("Not a matrix"), although, not for the same .LAS. I did not play much with the `max_edge` argument because I am not yet entirely sure of how it affects the algorithm.

The error I get from running the code in a loop (`tSearch()`) seems to refer to the triangulation part of the code.

Here's the error I would get running the code with a loop

```
Error in tSearch(D, P, X, threads) : Not a matrix.
```

Here's the error I would get running the code with LAScatalog

```
 An error occurred when processing the chunk 7. Try to load this chunk with:
 chunk <- readRDS("...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQ3rscv/chunk7.rds")
 las <- readLAS(chunk)
 Not a matrix.
```

I would like to know what I should look into to avoid this error but keep the same parameters for all my .LAS?

As suggested, I tried manipulating the chunk from the error. I put here my results in case it can be useful.

I am able to run pitfree() on it with different parameters (`las` is the chunk):

```
chm18 = grid_canopy(las, 0.5, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15,20))) #Without subcircle (error)
Error in tSearch(D, P, X, threads) : Not a matrix.

chm18 = grid_canopy(las, 0.5, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15,20), subcircle = 0.2)) #with subcircle (works)
chm18 = grid_canopy(las, 0.25, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15,20))) #res to 0.25 (works)
chm18 = grid_canopy(las, 1, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15,20))) #res to 1 (works)
```

I tried with the edge parameters too.

```
chm18 = grid_canopy(las, 0.5, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15,20), c(0,1)))
Error in tSearch(D, P, X, threads) : Not a matrix.
```

c(0,3), c(2,3), c(0,4) all worked though

Lastly, I changed the thresholds values :

```
chm19 = grid_canopy(las3, 0.5, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10))) #removed the 2 last tresholds (works)

chm19 = grid_canopy(las3, 0.5, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,14))) #tried last threshold set other than 15 (works)
```

Any threshold other that 15 would work (10,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,20)

Comment: There is clearly something that should be handled internally. What you should do first is to load the chunk number 7 and look the point cloud. Does it look good? Is there something special in it? Can you manage to run `pitfree()` on it. Bad parameters should fail with an error like `Interpolation failed. Input parameters might be wrong.` Here you found a limit case. I tested everything I can without being able to reproduce. If you think it is a bug please report with a reproducible example.

Comment: I looked the chunks point cloud and it seems normal to me. I also compared with other 5 files that gives the same error and I can't see something that make them different from other files. I have updated the original post with some info and results of playing around with the algorithm to see what works and what doesn't. Unfortunately, I cannot share the data to make it reproducible. I'll look what I can do if you think it would be useful to correct a bug or something.

Comment: You definitively found a bug. Please communicate with me preferably on github if possible or by email. We will try to reproduce and fix.

Comment: Could you please mention which version of the package your are using

Comment: Version is 2.1.3. I will get back to you for the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [bug fixed](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/issues/288) in version 2.1.4. In short in R when you subset a matrix you get a matrix (that makes sense) but when you subset a single row you get a vector instead of a `1 x n` matrix. R's behavior is inconsistent. In rare cases you may have a single remaining triangle in `pitfree()`. This is why you got an internal error `not a matrix`. This case is now handled.

Comment: I can confirm that it is working with my data as well after I updated to 2.1.4. Glad someone was able to provide you a reproducible example.